# Creating new .Net Core Console Process: Exception when using environment variables with UseShellExecute=true

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, process, console

I want to run a number of .Net Core console apps from a single console.
I have the following code:

```
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("c:\path\to\filename.exe", "arguments")
        {
            UseShellExecute = true,
            WorkingDirectory = "c:\working\directory",
        };
        var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

I receive the following exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to use environment variables.'`

Apps use variables from `appsettings.json` file in `WorkingDirectory`.

How to run the app processes successfully, each in a separate console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help

```csharp
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/K ""c:\path\to\filename.exe"" arguments")
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    WorkingDirectory = @"c:\working\directory",
    //CreateNoWindow = true
};
var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, although I still have to keep `UseShellExecute = true` to open a separate console window for each respected process. Otherwise, every process would send its output to the main calling console which defeats the purpose.

Comment: @user2341923 You may also redirect output and write it e.g to log files or `string`, or not write at all. Refer to `Process` docs.

Comment: @user2341923 check if better to use `/C` instead of `/K`.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is the top search result for the error message

> The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to use environment variables

, I thought I would chime in with an observation after looking through reference source for [EnvironmentVariables](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/ProcessStartInfo.cs,5611ad13d0b7376e) here
and comparing to the use of the *internal* backing variable in [ProcessStartInfo](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,2204) here.

Chances are, you're probably here because you're sitting in front of Visual Studio with a breakpoint trying to figure out what the right magic is to make UseShellExecute work.

If you look through the locals or immediate windows, or you serialize the ProcessStartInfo class object, or basically do anything that might directly or indirectly access ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables, the code will instantiate the collection and populate it! Then, when you actually try to start the process, the beginning part of the method throws out your config as invalid.

The only way to make UseShellExecute work is to ensure the environmentVariables backing field stays null, and to do that means, you can't access it any way (directly or indirectly).

Comment: thank you, that really closed this case of "now it works - now it doesn't ..." !!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I also fell into this trap. And I figured out how to actually use the `UseShellExecute` and NOT have the environmentVariables populated.

I did all that was recommended, except, I populated the `WorkingDirectory` too. And it did not work. Gave me that damn error message.

The source code for the `ProcessStartInfo` gives a hint to what's happening.

```
//
// Summary:
//     When the System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute property is false,
//     gets or sets the working directory for the process to be started. When System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute
//     is true, gets or sets the directory that contains the process to be started.
//
// Returns:
//     When System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute is true, the fully qualified
//     name of the directory that contains the process to be started. When the System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute
//     property is false, the working directory for the process to be started. The default
//     is an empty string ("").
```

**So, as soon as you touch the working directory, it also populates the environment variables.**

Solution: DONT SET A WORKING DIRECTORY when you want to UseShellExecute

*Also, when you debug it, right after creating a ProcessStartInfo and you inspect it, as soon as you inspect the value of the EnvironmentVariables member, it will be populated. Kind of confusing.*